# Calling Featured Image from generated thumbnail

Tags: wordpress

Current theme is set up to generate a thumbnail based on user input (variable height). I would like to have this thumbnail link to a full size featured image via prettyphoto. Current code calling generated thumb:

```
<?php
    //if our user has a post thumbnail
    //out featured image URL
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
?>

<?php if($src[0] != '') : //if user has featured image ?>
<img src="<?php echo ddTimthumb($src[0], $contentW, get_post_meta($post->ID, 'postThumbHeight', true)); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this just modify the classes and other attributes according to your need.

```
    <?php 
     if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
       $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
       echo '<a rel="prettyPhoto" href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
       the_post_thumbnail();
       echo '</a>';
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: close but not exactly what I was looking for. Your fix places the full version on the page. I was looking to have the thumbnail on the page with it linked to open to full size by user. So thumbnail is img src and the href link is full size image that has the prettyphoto class.

Comment: that is exactly what it is and like i said modify it to your needs ...

you need to have prettyphoto plugin installed for rel="prettyphpto" to make it work your small thumbnail will be displayed on page but you need to add your thumbnail name here `the_post_thumbnail('my-thumbnail');` my-thumbnail is dimensions of thumbnail that you define in functions file

Comment: completely missed that. worked perfectly. thank you.

Comment: i am glad that it worked :) can you mark the answer as correct so that other people can also use it.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually using this same thing in one of my project see the code link and see if that can help you :) and once again don't expect it to work by copy pasting this is just to give you an idea modify it to your needs :)

[Link to pastebin for code sample](http://pastebin.com/6AgnQFS2) (or see below)

```
<div class="row" id="gallery-main">
    <?php $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );
    query_posts($args); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="span4 portfolio-item">
            <?php
             if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
               $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
               echo '<a class="image-link pi-img" rel="prettyPhoto" href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';
               the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-listing');
               echo '<div class="hover-style"></div></a>';
             }
             ?>                
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```